# 404 page not working on Nextjs Static Generated File

Tags: next.js, custom-error-pages

Im having trouble to show 404 custom page i made when i generate static generated file (`next build && next export`)

When im navigating to non existing page ("`/<any-non-existing`"), it always redirects to homepage ("`/`"). My expectation is that it will automatically redirect to ("`/404`").

However, if im manually navigating to ("`/404`") page, the page works perfectly fine.

Deployed to S3 with Cloudfront
Enabled next.config.js `{ trailingSlash: true }`

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: Yes, since im using S3 as my static file storage, there is a configuration under **Static Website Hosting**. Set the value _Error document - optional_ to your specific 404 page.